# Too much "free memory"

Tags: xubuntu, 19.10, ram, memory-usage

I have extremely high "free memory". According to [this site here](https://www.linuxatemyram.com) it is better to have "free memory" as close to 0 as possible. What I understand is that this "free memory" is basically wasted memory as it is not being used at all.

If that is the case, how can I "release" this free memory or utilize this free memory? See below the free memory when I use `top` (typically it is much, much higher):

```
MiB Mem :   7829.3 total,   2952.5 free,   1766.8 used,   3110.0 buff/cache
MiB Swap:   2048.0 total,   2047.7 free,      0.2 used.   5727.4 avail Mem
```

FYI, I am using Xubuntu 19.10, Dual-boot with Windows 10, Core i5 2.5GHz if that helps.

Comment: The site explicitly says free memory will approach 0 _after running for a while_. You should run `free -m` (after some usage, the heavier the faster you will use memory). That being said, there is no reason why a lightly used system should use tons of memory if it is not doing much and what it does deals with the same buffers over and over.

Comment: Free memory will eventually be used in the "used" or "buff/cache" figures. Nothing is wrong here.

Comment: @EduardoTrápani yep that's right. missed that part. i will take your advice and keep an eye on the usage. thanks!